# Silverlight: Datagrid like grouping in ItemsControl

Tags: silverlight, listbox, grouping, itemscontrol

Is it possible to group items in a ItemsControl or Listbox in Silverlight? These controls are bound to a DomainDataSource.

Or are there any 3rd party controls that do this?

**UPDATE:**

This is the sort of UI I am trying to create.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by using nested `ItemsControls` bound to a [PagedCollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.pagedcollectionview(v=vs.95).aspx).

Say I have a datasource - `MyItems` - with fields: `Category`, `Section` and `Option`. I can create a `PagedCollectionView` from an `IEnumerable(of MyItems)` and tell it which fields to group by.

```
Dim original As IEnumerable(Of MyItems) = GetMyItems()

Dim pcv = New PagedCollectionView(original)

pcv.GroupDescriptions.Add(New PropertyGroupDescription("Category"))
pcv.GroupDescriptions.Add(New PropertyGroupDescription("Section"))
```

Then I bind my first `ItemsControl` to the `PagedCollectionView`

```
hisMyItems.ItemsSource = pcv.Groups
```

The `PCV` creates a nested hierachy like:

```
-Name
    -Items
```

where `Name` is the value in the grouped field and `Items` contains the rows/objects in that grouping. I guess you could also create the PCV in xaml if you prefer.

The xaml would look something like:

```
<controls:HeaderedItemsControl x:Name="hisMyItems" Header="{Binding Name}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
    <controls:HeaderedItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

            <controls:HeaderedItemsControl Header="{Binding Name}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource ItemsPanelTemplate1}" >
                <controls:HeaderedItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="{Binding Option}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </controls:HeaderedItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </controls:HeaderedItemsControl>

        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:HeaderedItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</controls:HeaderedItemsControl>
```

I hope that makes sense. I have tried to simplify things from my actual app but I could have made some mistakes in copying it over. Obviously you could use normal ItemsControls or other controls too and customize with templates etc.

Answer (score 0):

The DataGrid control supports grouping.

Tim Heuer has a good blog on grouping with a datagrid. 
[link text](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/04/08/grouping-in-silverlight-datagrid.aspx)

Comment: Yes I know, but the datagrid is not really suitable for what I want. I want to show a single control(eg Button) for each row but these need to wrap horizontally rather than vertically. So in the ItemsControl you can style the ItemsPanel to use a wrappanel but I cant see a way to do this in the datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the control you are really looking for is the Accordian Control from the [Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/).

See sample of Accordian behaviour [here](http://silverlight.net/content/samples/sl3/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html).

Note that the actual appearance is as style-able as any other control.  The basic function is to group categories of items that would otherwise be a straight-forward List.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. I'm not sure that this will support grouping from a domaindatasource though. Also I need more than 1 level of grouping.

Comment: Hmm.. I see from you comment to Stephen your true requirement and question is kinda of revealed.  Its not clear exactly how the idea of "Grouping" is compatiable with a "Wrappanel" style layout?  I suggest you edit your question state categorically what actual UI you really want to acheive.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones- I've added a image of what I am trying to create. I was looking for a control to do this using databinding but it looks like I am just going to have to write some code to manually create the UI.