# Silverlight 3 Datagrid: Template rows container

Tags: silverlight, templates, datagrid, coding-style

Is it possible to template the container for datagrid rows so that they can wrap horizontally? eg in the ItemsControl you can simply change the ItemsPanel to use a WrapPanel.

I can't use a ItemsControl because I want to use the Grouping support in the DataGrid when bound to a DomainDataSource.

Comment: What appearance should the Grouping take?  Are you looking for Grouping to appear the same as it would by default and only the "Detail" section to be a wrap panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is a simple: No.

The `DataGrid` requires that the `DataGridRowsPresenter` primitive control be used to present the rows.  This handles the layout of both the Rows and the Group header rows.  It does not support any styling that would change the way it lays these controls out.

You can't replace the `DataGridRowsPresenter` with a different control, code internal to the `DataGrid` class assume that there is a control in its template with the name "RowsPresenter" that can directly cast to the type `DataGridRowsPresenter`.

Comment: The image in this related question clarifies what I am trying to achieve. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019942/silverlight-3-datagrid-like-grouping-in-itemscontrol